# How get the value of the attribute provide to a method in C#

Tags: c#

```
public class A
{
    [Description("This method does something")]
    public void TestMethod()
     {
       //Do Something
     }
}
```

My question is how do I get the string value of the Description Attribute using reflection.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkattributestutorialanchor3

Answer (score 1):

```
var description = ((DescriptionAttribute)typeof (A).GetMethod("TestMethod")
    .GetCustomAttribute(typeof (DescriptionAttribute))).Description;
```

Comment: public void GetDescription()
        {
            MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(A).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            Dictionary<string , string > methodInformations = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach(var method in methods)
            {
                object attrs = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute));

                DescriptionAttribute decr = attrs as DescriptionAttribute;

                methodInformations.Add(method.Name, decr.Description);
            }
        }

Comment: The above method also helped me in filtering the base class method as the class A was a derived class

Answer (score 0):

You can try like  this:

```
MethodBase m = typeof(A).GetMethod("TestMethod");;
Description d = (Description)m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Description), true)[0] ;
string str= d.Value;
```